# Remove duplicates from a MySQL table using Talend

Tags: mysql, talend

Coming from SAS background, I am finding this basic task of deduping a dataset quite a chore with Talend. I am certain that it's to do with the lack of my experience with the tool.

I need to remove duplicates from a target dataset, after inserting the data. I can't seem to run multiple sql statements using tSortRow (MySQL) and I get the error - "You have an error in your SQL syntax". The set of queries work fine on the MySQL Workbench.

With SAS Data Management Studio, I could add a SAS code node and could run this sort procedure with noduplicates modifier. I was trying to do something similar by running the set of SQL queries, through tMySQLRow component.

How do you guys do that? All I need is the talend way to deduplicate the data in the datasource.

Comment: please include a sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to de-duplicate table data by doing the following within a subjob:

tDBInput --> tAggregate (count by value) --> tFilterRow (where count is greater than 1 for your duplicate fields)

[image: subjob]

Alternatively, since you're using MySQL, you should be able to remove the duplicates via SQL. Do you have a sample schema of the table?

Comment: That one seems like a good solution. However, I missed to add that I was updating a table and post update I wanted to dedup. In the same flow, I added another tMySQLRow node and added sql code statements in it.

[code]
create table data_hub.tmp_uniq as select distinct * from data_hub.datahub_securities group by cusip order by id desc;

delete from data_hub.datahub_securities;
    insert into data_hub.datahub_securities select * from data_hub.tmp_uniq;
    drop table data_hub.tmp_uniq;
[/code]

Comment: @SushantVasishta I don't believe you need to use Talend for this, do you have the schema of the table you are loading into and removing duplicates from?

Comment: I hear what you are trying to say. The comparison logic is rather fuzzy and I haven't been able to ascertain how I can insert (or update) only selected records. I then chose to insert all the records and remove the old ones, if they are duplicate. Ideally, I would just want to udpate the record, based on uniqueness of combination of fields.

Comment: @SushantVasishta there is tFuzzyMatch under Data Quality > Matching. Take a look at that and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

There is an inbuilt component by talend for removing duplicate values tuniquerow which will load to the target after removing the duplicate records

tDBInput_1 ----> tUniqueRow_1 --->target

**Note:You need to specify the key column for which your checking the duplicate values in tUniqueRow**